# python pandas dataframe smallest values with uncertaintties package

Tags: python, pandas

I am combining pandas dataframes and ufloat as shown below. Worked good enough for a while, now I have a problem if I want to use the nsmallest function on a ufloat column. This is the error message:

> TypeError: Column 'x' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nsmallest'
>   with this dtype

maybe putting a ufloat into the dataframe is not the best idea. Are there better ways of combining uncertainties and dataframes? Or can one work around this problem easily?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from uncertainties import unumpy as unp

x = unp.uarray([1, 2, 3], [0.11, 0.21, 0.3])
y = unp.uarray([5, 4, 3], [0.21, 0.08, 0.23])
bar = np.array([7.2, 5.1, 3.7])

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':x, 'y':y, 'bar':bar })
df["z"] = df["x"]**2 + 2*df["y"]
df["zz"] = 1/df["x"] + unp.sin(df["y"])

print df.nsmallest(1, "x")
```

Edit: The desired output is the full dataframe (so similar to print df.nsmallest(1, "bar")), just for the entry with the smallest unumpy.nominal_values(df["x"]). In this particular case this would be the same as nlargest(1, "bar"), so

```
   bar            x            y           z           zz
0  7.2  1.00+/-0.11  5.00+/-0.21  11.0+/-0.5  0.04+/-0.13
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the expected output

Comment: On what basis the output is decided ? Only on nominal value or some other parameters also ?

Comment: Well for now only nominal value would be sufficient. However, would be great if one could extent the solution, let's say to absolute and relative uncertainties, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code might help you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from uncertainties import unumpy as unp

x = unp.uarray([1, 2, 3], [0.11, 0.21, 0.3])
y = unp.uarray([5, 4, 3], [0.21, 0.08, 0.23])
bar = np.array([7.2, 5.1, 3.7])

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':x, 'y':y, 'bar':bar })
df["z"] = df["x"]**2 + 2*df["y"]
df["zz"] = 1/df["x"] + unp.sin(df["y"])

# print(df)

temp_smallest_nominal = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.nominal_value).nsmallest(1)
temp_largest_nominal = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.nominal_value).nlargest(1)
print(df.loc[df.index == temp_smallest_nominal.index[0]])
print(df.loc[df.index == temp_largest_nominal.index[0]])


temp_smallest_std_devs = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.std_dev).nsmallest(1)
temp_largest_std_devs = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.std_dev).nsmallest(1)
print(df.loc[df.index == temp_smallest_std_devs.index[0]])
print(df.loc[df.index == temp_largest_std_devs.index[0]])


temp_list_of_smallest = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.nominal_value).nsmallest(2)
print(df.loc[df.index.isin(temp_list_of_smallest.index)])
```

**temp_smallest_nominal** is used to filter row with smallest nominal value

**temp_smallest_std_devs** is used to filter row with smallest std_dev value

**temp_list_of_smallest** is used to filter row with 'n' smallest value

Similarly for largest values.

Also you can change lambda function if you want to filter data on different basis.

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot, thanks. Using a lambda function here is a good solution, I would say